# Unknown compression (Decompression reversed)

Tags: decompress

I've reversed a decompression routine, but have to figure out the compression.

Because the executable only decrypts and therefor has no compression routine and I'm not comfortable with compressions it's really hard for me.

Here the code I've written in C#:

```
private unsafe void Decompress(byte[] decom, byte[] com, int comSize) {
        byte[] dict = new byte[4096];
        fixed (byte* pDict = dict, p1 = decom, p2 = com) {
            byte* pDecom = p1, pCom = p2;

            byte next;
            int r6 = 0, r7 = 0xfee, r10, r9;

            while (true) {
                r6 >>= 1;

                if ((r6 & 0x100) == 0) {
                    if (comSize-- == 0)
                        return;

                    r6 = 0xFF00 | *(pCom++);
                }

                if ((r6 & 1) == 1) {
                    if (comSize-- == 0)
                        return;

                    next = *(pCom++);
                    *(pDecom++) = next;
                    *(pDict + r7) = next;
                    r7 = (r7 + 1) & 0xFFF;
                } else {
                    if ((comSize -= 2) <= 0)
                        return;

                    r10 = (*(pCom++) << 8) | *(pCom++);

                    r9 = r10 >> 4;
                    r10 = (r10 & 0xF) + 2;

                    for (int i = r10 + 1; i > 0; --i) {
                        r10 = r9++ & 0xFFF;
                        next = *(pDict + r10);
                        *(pDecom++) = next;
                        *(pDict + r7) = next;
                        r7 = (r7 + 1) & 0xfff;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It would be nice if someone could identify or post a link to code for the compression.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.compression/XuHhTgom-xM), that appears to be an [LZ77](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78#LZ77) variant.